# GDB inferior_call event not get triggered

Tags: c, gdb

This is the python script: events.py

```py
import gdb
def inferior_call_handler (event):
    print(event)

gdb.events.inferior_call.connect(inferior_call_handler)
```

run GDB with:

```sh
gdb --batch --command=../events.py --args ~/codes/coreutils/src/ls
```

No event printed.

Comment: Why do you expect an event printed? Which function did gdb call?

Comment: Actually, I expected any function in the inferior gets called would trigger this event , like the 'rbreak .*' command. Is this possible? @ssbssa

Comment: An inferior_call event is emitted `just before and after a function in the inferior is called by GDB`. That doesn't include the functions normally called from inside the program, but e.g. when you do a `print some_function()` in gdb. If `rbreak` works for you, used it and try to combine it with the `stop` event.

Comment: @ssbssa I got it！thanks！